# Append data to top of the JSON file using PHP

Tags: php

I am appending data to JSON file using a PHP form, But right now it adds the new data to the bottom in JSON file

I want to add new data to top in JSON file instead of bottom.

Here is My PHP code which i am using to append data to JSON.

```
<?php  
 $message = '';  
 $error = '';  
 if(isset($_POST["submit"]))  
 {  
      if(empty($_POST["name"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Name</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["author"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Author</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["category"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter Thumbnail</label>";  
      }  
      else if(empty($_POST["url"]))  
      {  
           $error = "<label class='text-danger'>Enter URL</label>";  
      }  
      else  
      {  
          if(file_exists('wallpaper.json'))  
          {  
               $current_data = file_get_contents('wallpaper.json');  
               $array_data = json_decode($current_data, true);  
               $extra = array(  
                    'name'               =>     $_POST['name'],  
                    'author'          =>     $_POST["author"],  
                    'category'     =>     $_POST["category"],  
                    'url'     =>     $_POST["url"]  

               );  
               $array_data[] = $extra;  
               $final_data = json_encode($array_data);  
               if(file_put_contents('wallpaper.json', $final_data))  
               {  
                    $message = "<label class='text-success'>File Appended Success fully</p>";  
               }  
          }  
          else  
          {  
               $error = 'JSON File not exits';  
          }  
     }  
 }
 ?>
```

Here is the wallpaper.JSON currently it adds data like this -

```
[
  {
    "name": "Old Code",
    "author": "Old Code",
    "category": "Old Code",
    "url": "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/11851.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "New Code",
    "author": "New Code",
    "category": "New Code",
    "url": "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/11851.jpg"
  }
]
```

I want it like this -

```
[
  {
    "name": "New Code",
    "author": "New Code",
    "category": "New Code",
    "url": "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/11851.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Old Code",
    "author": "Old Code",
    "category": "Old Code",
    "url": "https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/11851.jpg"
  }
]
```

Comment: Please don't just repost questions unless you have updated the question with some effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well You can use use array_reverse in your use case but I would do the other approach

```
$array_data[] = $extra;  
$array_data = array_reverse($array_data);
$final_data = json_encode($array_data);
```

But a better approach would be to use array_unshift

```
array_unshift($array_data, $extra);
```

Source: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php

Comment: Thank you so much, just did the same thing 1 minute before your answer.

Comment: You Are Welcome @user9157668